# How do I remote into multiple remote computers via PS to discover one specific app and determine the version number on each remote device? No output

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-remoting

FYI: I'm very new to PS and I'm using this as a learning opportunity. Again, I'm trying to find a
specific application on a list of multiple remote devices and determine the version number of the
application on their corresponding host system. I attempted this via a registry query (found this to
be challenging) and then I used Get-WMIObject. As of now, I'm working with this as my script. It's
not producing any output; instead, it returns to the command prompt with no errors or messages.

Script to find specific application and version in multiple remote devices:

```
    $Servers = Get-Content -Path C:\\files\Serverlist.txt

    $CIMSession = New-CIMSession -ComputerName $Servers Get-Credentials

    $Vendor = "App Name"


    foreach($Serv in $Servers) {

    If(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Serv -Count 1 -Quiet) {

    $Status = Get-Ciminstance Win32_Product -Computername $Serv | Where-object {$_.Version -contains 
    $Vendor}

    if($Status) {

    Out-file -Filepath C:\\files\AppVerResults.txt

    }

    }

    }
```

I also tried adjusting the following section of the script as shown below but it presented me with the error "Get-CimInstance : Access is denied." Is this error message due to group policy or so? I am able to remote into the device corresponding to the message via RDP.

```
    if($Status) {

     $Servers + " - "

    $Status | Out-file -Filepath C:\\files\AppVerResults.txt

    }

    }

    }
```

Should I go about it via invoke-command or registry query? I'm slowly picking things up so I'll continue my research but I was hoping to get some advice in the meantime.

Comment: Access denied on CIM Session can mean many things, I would have a good read at PowerShell remoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still believe searching the registry is the easier way to go unless you have the specific file path for the *.exe*.

Use this function to find software on a remote, or local PC. Theres a *filter* option by specifying `-SoftwareName` (*to look for*).

- `Find-Software -ComputerName Remote_ComputerName -SoftwareName 'SQL'`

Also accepts pipeline input, as well as multiple computer names to query for.

- `Find-Software -ComputerName ComputerOne, ComputerTwo, ComputerThree -SoftwareName 'SQL'`
- `'ComputerOne','ComputerTwo' | Find-Software -SoftwareName 'SQL'`
- Exporting is also allowed by piping to an `Export-*` cmdlet.

Heres the code:

```
Function Find-Software {
[cmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipeLine=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeLineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('cn','name')]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [String]$SoftwareName
         )
Begin{

    #Get Computer Names to check software version for
    $Server_List = Get-Content -Path "C:\files\Serverlist.txt"
    
    #Get Credentials for Script Scope once.
    $Credentials = Get-Credential

}

Process{
    if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SoftwareName')){
        foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
            Try{

            $PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credentials -EnableNetworkAccess -ErrorAction Stop

            $Software_List = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { 
                                Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*",
                                                 "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" } -Session $PSSession

            $Software_List = $Software_List | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.DisplayName -match $SoftwareName} | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName
                foreach($Software in $Software_List){
                    if($Software){
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "Computer Name" = $Computer
                            "Software Name" = $Software.DisplayName
                            "  Version  "   = $Software.DisplayVersion
                            }
                        } else {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "Computer Name" = $Computer
                            "Software Name" = "Not found"
                            "  Version  "   = $null
                        }
                    }
                }

            } Catch {
                "Unable to connect to PC: $Computer"
                "Error: $($Error[0].Message.Split('.')[1].Trim())"
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
            Try{

            $PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credentials -EnableNetworkAccess -ErrorAction Stop

            $Software_List = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { 
                                Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*",
                                                 "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" } -Session $PSSession
                                                 
            $Software_List = $Software_List | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName
                foreach($Software in $Software_List){
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "Computer Name" = $Computer
                            "Software Name" = $Software.DisplayName
                            "  Version  "   = $Software.DisplayVersion
                            }
                        }
                    } Catch {
                        "Unable to connect to PC: $Computer"
                        "Error: $($Error[0].Message.Split('.')[1].Trim())"
                    }
                }
            } #end ELSE statement
        } #end PROCESS block
    End {
        if(Get-PSSession){
            Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
        }
    } #end END block - Perform Session Clean Up
} #end FUNCTION
```

Simply modify it to fit your needs :)